# Why does my array not immediately update after sending a GET request in JS?

Tags: javascript, post, get

My goal is to create a single page email application with Javascript and HTML. The web framework I'm using is Django and according to the project guidelines, I should only be writing JS and HTML(so we can assume everything *but* my JS and HTML is correct).

My issue is that after I compose an email in the "compose" section of my app, I should be sent directly to the "sent" section where I can see all the emails I've sent including the one I *just* sent. For some reason, I'm unable to see the email I just sent. Only when I reload the page does it appear, which is not what I want. The below two snippets of code belongs to a file called **inbox.js**:

**compose_email**

```
function compose_email() {
    // Show compose view and hide other views
    document.querySelector("#emails-view").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector("#compose-view").style.display = "block";

    const recipients = document.querySelector("#compose-recipients");
    const subject = document.querySelector("#compose-subject");
    const body = document.querySelector("#compose-body");

    //   Clear out composition fields
    recipients.value = "";
    subject.value = "";
    body.value = "";

    document.querySelector("form").onsubmit = function () {
        const recipients = document.querySelector("#compose-recipients").value;
        const subject = document.querySelector("#compose-subject").value;
        const body = document.querySelector("#compose-body").value;

        fetch("/emails", {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
                recipients: recipients,
                subject: subject,
                body: body,
            }),
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((result) => {
                //result is just a message to let me know if the email was sent successfully
                console.log(result);
            });

        load_mailbox("sent");
        return false;
    };
}
```

**load_mailbox**

```
function load_mailbox(mailbox) {
    // Show the mailbox and hide other views
    document.querySelector("#emails-view").style.display = "block";
    document.querySelector("#compose-view").style.display = "none";

    // Show the mailbox name
    document.querySelector("#emails-view").innerHTML = `<h3>${
        mailbox.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + mailbox.slice(1)
    }</h3>`;

    //this is where I'm having issues
    if (mailbox === "sent") {
        fetch("/emails/sent")
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((emails) => {
                //when I console.log(emails) after being directly sent to this function by compose_email I get an array that does not have the email I just sent.
                console.log(emails);
                for (var email of emails) {
                    document.querySelector("#emails-view").innerHTML += `
                    <div class="card bg-light">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-4">${email.recipients}</div>
                                <div class="col-4">${email.subject}</div>
                                <div class="col-4">${email.timestamp}</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    `;
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not waiting for the request to finish

Comment: @CertainPerformance from what I've read in [this post about asynchronous code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron) it seems that my `fetch("/emails/sent")` method is asynchronous. If I'm not waiting for the request to finish, how do I wait for it to finish using a callback?

Comment: Call `load_mailbox("sent");` only after the `/emails` request finishes - in its `.then`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want one more .then(() => {load_mailbox("sent")}). Otherwise you're redirecting to sent before your fetch finishes.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks, that solved my problem!